# Auto Set VLAN ID Hyper-V 2012 R2 Cloud

Tags: hyper-v, vlan

I have a lab environment with multiple clouds configured in Hyper-V SCVMM. When a guest machine is created in the correct cloud say "Yellow" it is randomly given one of the 5 Vlans we use. If it is wrong, the Lab Admin has to manually change it.

I would like for the VM's to automatically be created with the correct VLAN AND/OR enable the guests to change this option without giving them full admin rights. Perhaps a powershell scrip that could be run from within the host?

I suspect I may have left out some information, please let me know what you need and I will get back ASAP.

Comment: `I suspect I may have left out some information`... like, how do you know what the correct vlan will be? What is it that makes a VM part of the wrong cloud?

Comment: I know that Yellow is VLAN 90. Users can only create VM's in the correct cloud, they just get a random VLAN